# Jquery autocomplete not working on bootstrap 4 modal

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-4

I have been trying to convert my MVC web application from Bootstrap 3 to 4.  The modals section has not been easy. The modal loads a partial view. The autocomplete which worked previously in BS3 still is not working.  It works if I browse to the partial view using its own window. (sitename/area/controller/_action/id)

Here is the jquery running on document ready function in a separate js file that opens the modal and loads the partial view into it.

```
$('body').on('click', '.modal-link', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).attr('data-target', '#modal-container');
        $(this).attr('data-toggle', 'modal');
        //$('#modal-container').modal('show');
        $('#modal-container').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
            var button = $(event.relatedTarget); // Button that triggered the modal
            var url = button.attr("href");
            var modal = $(this);
            // note that this will replace the content of modal-content everytime the modal is opened
            modal.find('.modal-content').load(url);
        });        
    });
```

Here is the part of the partial view, in BS3 to make this work I had to reference a bunch of scripts from the partial view because the modal does not inherit the scripts from the full views (i think this was why).

```
<div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.yPlayerID, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <input type="text" id="PlayerText" placeholder="@(ViewBag.Name)" autocomplete="on" style="min-width:250px" />
                </div>
            </div>
```

Here is the scripts section in the partial view (note there is a lot of comments etc because I have been troubleshooting and trying different things):

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/start/jquery-ui.css">
<link href="~/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    //Autocomplete on Certain Text Boxes
    //alert($("#draftID#").val());
    //$('#modal-container').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
    //    alert("modalshowing");
    //})
    $("#PlayerText").autocomplete({
        delay: 500,
        minLength: 3,
        source: function (request, response) {
            //debugger;
            $.ajax({
                url: '/FFDraft/DraftBoard/GetPlayers',
                method: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                data: {
                    prefix: request.term
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data, function (item) {
                        return { label: item.name, value: item.val };
                    }))
                }
            });
        },
        select: function (event, ui) {
            // prevent autocomplete from updating the textbox
            event.preventDefault();
            //Populate Fields
            $(this).val(ui.item.label);
            $("#yPlayerID").val(ui.item.value);
        }
    });
</script>
```

Any ideas?  There is probably a lot of unnecessary code here since I am not an expert with this stuff and once I get something working I don't like removing it in case it borks something else.

Comment: Scripts should never be in partial views (and since you must have jquery loaded in the main view, your now loading a 2nd copy of jquery). You need to initialize the plugin in the success callback of your ajax call when you add the partial

Comment: And you have noted _in the scripts section_ - if you mean in `@section scripts {` then your not loading anything since sections are not supported in partials

Comment: No, I just meant the bottom part of the view, not a section. I thought I read somewhere that partial views loaded in a modal needed their own scripts loaded.  I will work wiht your advice and see what I can come up with.  Which plugin do I need to initialize?  It stupifies me that this all worked fine when I was using Bootstrap 3, now in 4 it all broke.

Comment: Now I remember, the "_layout" part of my main views isnt loaded in the partial this "_layout" is where I define all my styles and scripts, thats why I do it again in the partial.

Comment: Which means your duplicating scripts - `jquery.js` is loaded in the main view (via the layout) and you load another copy when the partial is loaded which will wipe out every script you previously loaded that depends on jquery. Again, script NEVER go in partial views

Comment: I dont understand though, if I place all those scripts i referenced in my partial view in the main view, my autocomplete no longer works, which makes me think the modal/partial is not using those same scripts referenced in the main view.

Comment: I was able to get this working with a simple style note on the main view.

Comment: <style>
        .ui-autocomplete {
            z-index: 99999999 !important;
        }
    </style>

Comment: The 2 <script src=...`>` and `<link rel="..` tags go in the main view or layout, and the code to initialize the plugin goes in the ajax success callback (after you have added the partial to the DOM - `modal.find('.modal-content').load(url, function() { $("#PlayerText").autocomplete({ ....`